# OWASP zap run in command promt

Tags: automation, automated-tests, owasp

Is there any way to run OWASP zap in CMD mode?

1. I have selenium scripts it opens the browser and runs.
2. When running it auto record all the requests to Zap (already completed).
3. Now I need to run the OWASP zap zed using Jenkins or using selenium.

Is there any way to do this?

Change the standard mode to attack mode and execute the attack, then email the HTML report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is! You can use the [zap CLI](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli) for that. The CLI let you start an active scan and get the report. There is also the [base line scan](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-Baseline-Scan) that is bundled in the docker image, and you can always use the [API](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiDetails) directly. Each one of these approaches can let you achieve what you want - besides sending an email. This can be done (I hope) with Jenkins.